# Error installing angular translate local storage

Tags: bower, angular-translate, bower-install

I have problem of installing angular translate local storage using "bower install angular-translate-storage-local --save-dev" in mac terminal. It just shows this error 'ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/^1/2.git", exit code of #128'.

[image]

Please help. I have tried 'git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://' but it still does not work.

Note: I use bower version 1.7.9.

Answer (score 0):

> git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://

I hope this will solve your problem. Please refer below same git issue.

https://github.com/Hacklone/private-bower/issues/102